# Show internal server error?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, web-config, azure-web-roles

I have the following output when running my web application:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

In my `web.config`, the following are set:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
</system.webServer>
```

How do I see what the error is?

This is hosted locally in the Azure Compute Emulator.

Comment: Are you using IE? Try disabling "Show friendly HTTP error messages". Go to the "Tools" menu, select "Internet Options", click the "Advanced" tab and find the "Show friendly HTTP error messages" check box and uncheck it.

Comment: Setting customErrors and httpErrors like this lets me see the detailed errors (in FF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the configurations you have done, if you are using Internet Explorer, turn off the option "Show friendly HTTP error messages" in the "Advanced" tab.

Another option is to [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your application so you can use the [trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to look for exceptions.

You might also find value in deploying [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) with your application for improved error handling.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to various reasons. Most likely some **misconfiguration**.

In my case it was the LocalWebDevelopmentServer setting. Setting it to `IISExpress` fixed the problem.[image]